# Use map and filter instead of a for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, functional-programming

How do I write an equivalent of the code below using map and filter?

```
res = []
for x in range(5):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        for y in range(5):
            if y % 2 == 1:  
                res.append((x, y))
```

This is the expected result:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)]
```

Here's the code I wrote, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
list( map(( lambda x,y: (x,y)), filter((lambda x: x%2 == 0), range(5)), filter((lambda y: y%2 != 0), range(5))))
```

Comment: Comparing your own two approaches, mind that [readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I just wanted to understand map and filter better. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as (in Python 2.x):

```
xs = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(5))
ys = filter(lambda y: y % 2 == 1, range(5))
res = [(x, y) for x in xs for y in ys]
```

This also uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

In Python 3.x:

```
xs = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(5)))
ys = list(filter(lambda y: y % 2 == 1, range(5)))
res = [(x, y) for x in xs for y in ys]
```

Comment: This gives `[(0, 1), (0, 3)]` in 3.X. The filter objects need to be wrapped in list(). It worked when I did this. Thanks a lot for your answer!

`xs = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(5)))
ys = list(filter(lambda y: y % 2 == 1, range(5)))
res = [(x, y) for x in xs for y in ys]`

Comment: @Taiwosam: thanks for your comment. I have updated the answer to make it clear for others.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need map and filter, you could do the whole thing in a list comprehension

```
[(x,y) for x in range(5) for y in range(5) if not x%2 and y%2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) method from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), which produces cartesian product of input iterables.

```
x_arr = [x for x in range(5) if x % 2 == 0]
y_arr = [y for y in range(5) if x % 2 == 1]
from itertools import product
final_arr = product(x_arr, y_arr)
```

Output would be `[(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, you can make use of the fact that odd or even numbers can be captured by using the 3rd `step` argument of `range`:

```
>>> sorted((x,y) for y in range(1,5,2) for x in range(0,5,2))
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)]
```